# Is possible use driver and receiver from different RS232 IC?

Tags: rs232

I need **RS232 IC** with Features: **power supply 3.3v**, **ESD protection**, **8-drivers/8-receivers**.  I'm looking for ic with these specifications are not found.

These needs can be met if I use two IC is **SP3244E** (3-driver/5-receiver) and **SP3249E** (5-driver/3-receiver). **My question**: Can I use two IC above if I need **8-driver/8-receiver**? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, if the specs of both meet your needs.

Before the MAX232-style charge pump devices came on the scene, it was normal to use a 1488 in the transmit path and a 1489 in the receive path.  Perhaps there were bidirectional external-supply-required parts available, but they don't seem to have been very popular; rather most shipping products stayed with the 1488 & 1489 until they went to the charge pump solutions.